Генерация случайных чисел в CUDA C
Нужно сгенерировать случайное число от 1 до x в ядре функции CUDA C, насколько я знаю есть curand, но я вообще не понял как с ним работать.

А что документация говорит?

@MBo, документация не для слабых духом: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html. Внутри есть примеры.

Задавайте конкретный вопрос: "Я сделал так-то. Оно не работает. Как быть?". А "вообще не понял" не чинится.

Генерация случайных чисел на CUDA-девайсе.
